# Does daughter allowed to live with her parents after marriage?

Tags: children, family

Assalamulekum wa rahmatullah wa barkatahu

I m from india.if I have two daughters and they grown up and get married and start living with their husband  after that I will be living alone right?

I want to live in joint family because I love children and teens a lot.

Can daughter allowed to lived with their parents after married?

If not, I promise that I will hate to have daughter.

Comment: Tbh, you sound like an unmarried young adult who is still emotionally immature. Inshallah with time, you will realize the folly of your ways and be more erudite. But in short, even though nothing in Islam prohibits a daughter living with her parents after marriage, it is highly unlikely her husband would like to stay long term with his in laws.

Comment: Is this a serious question? How old are you? Any father or mother who are not selfish would whish their kids to live on their own with their husbands/wives if possible. The sunnah of our prophet was to have a home for each of his wives ...

Comment: Sassir I respect sunnah...I will live in joint family whether you like it or not I will love in joint family till my very death.....there is no life with no friends, no relations, especially no family....your and mine ideas is different thats why we don't understand each other....